# How can I solve Computed property "search" was assigned to but it has no setter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I use vue js version 2

My child component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <div class="search-sm">
            <b-input placeholder="Search"  @input="(val) => searchChange(val)" />
        </div>
    ...
</template>
<script>

export default {
  props: [
    "searchChange",
  ]
};
</script>
```

When search, it will call method in parent component

The parent component like this :

```
<template>
  ...
      <page-heading
        :searchChange="searchChange"
      ></page-heading>
  ...
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import PageHeading from "@/views/app/reports/PageHeading";

export default {
  components: {
    "page-heading": PageHeading,
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getReports"]),
    searchChange(val) {
      this.search = val;
      this.page = 1;
    },
    changePage(pageNum) {
      this.page = pageNum;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      page: "reportPage",
      search: "reportSearch",
    }),
  },
  watch: {
    search() {
      this.page = 1;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getReports();
  }
};
</script>
```

I use vuex store. It's like this :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const state = {
  page: 1,
  search: "",
}

const getters = {
  reportSearch: state => state.search,
  reportPage: state => state.page,
}

const mutations = {
  getReportSuccess (state, res) {
    state.total = res.data.length;
    state.perPage = res.perPage;
  },
}

const actions = {
  getReports ({ commit }) {
    axios
      ...
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

When I try to search there exist error like this :

[Vue warn]: Computed property "page" was assigned to but it has no setter.

How can I solve this problem?

Please help. Thank you very much

Comment: so is the error `Computed property "search" was assigned to but it has no setter.` or `Computed property "page" was assigned to but it has no setter.` - your title says one thing, your question says a different thing .... the issue is that `page` is a `computed` property, but your code does `this.page=1`

Comment: also, in your vuex store, state include `page` and `search` ... and your mutations refer to `state.total` and `state.perPage` - so ... what are these things?

Comment: @aromanda X I don't show all my code. I only show part of it because I think there is no need to show all the code

Comment: sure, so the second comment may be irrelevant, but the first comment is what you need to address - it's very rare that you want a `computed` to have a setter - but it is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

Comment: @Jaromanda X It seems to update the page to the first page every time you do a search

Comment: no idea what you mean, but I've posted a link to how to put a setter on a computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things

- a mapped getter for page and search

  ```js
    ...mapGetters({
      page: "reportPage",
      search: "reportSearch",
    }),
  ```
- and a mutation of the getters

  ```js
    searchChange(val) {
      this.search = val;
      this.page = 1;
    },
  ```

vuex getters don't have setters, you have to invoke a mutation manually

to get around that, you need to invoke the vuex action to update the state

```js
const mutations = {
  getReportSuccess (state, res) {
    state.total = res.data.length;
    state.perPage = res.perPage;
  },
  setReportPage(state, page) {
    state.reportPage = page;
  },
  setReportSearch(state, search) {
    state.reportSearch = search;
  },
}

const actions = {
  getReports ({ commit }) {
    axios
      ...
  },
  setPage({commit}, page) {
    commit('setReportPage', page);
  },
  setSearch({commit}, search) {
    commit('setReportSearch', search);
  },
}
```

this will add the actions and mutations needed to update individually

then instead of these methods:

```js
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getReports"]),
    searchChange(val) {
      this.search = val;
      this.page = 1;
    },
    changePage(pageNum) {
      this.page = pageNum;
    },
  },
```

you would have

```js
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getReports", "setPage", "setSearch"]),
    searchChange(val) {
      this.setSearch(val);
      this.setPage(1);
    },
    changePage(pageNum) {
      this.setPage(pageNum);
    },
  },
```

and the watch can be

```
  watch: {
    search() {
      this.setPage(1);
    },
  },
```

#### alternatively...

you could use a computed with a set and get like

```js
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("reportPage","reportSearch"]),
    page: 
      get: function () {
        return this.reportPage;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this.setPage(value)
      },
    search: 
      // or if you don't map getters and actions ...
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.getter.reportSearch;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this.$store.commit("setSearch", value);
        this.$store.commit("setPage", 1); // optional if you want to remove use of `searchChange`
      },
  },
```

this approach would allow you to map the v-model

```
<b-input placeholder="Search" v-model="search" />
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Same as I tried last night. But my problem now is how do I send search and page to getReports action? So I get the data according to the filter

Comment: I created a new question about this case. Maybe you can help me. Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434454/why-line-number-doesnt-work-when-click-on-another-page

Comment: Hi. What is your opinion?