# How can I using momentJS globally in VueJS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, momentjs

I use vue js version 2.6.11

I try to set up in main.js like this :

```js
import moment from 'moment'
moment.locale('nl');
Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

But there exist error :

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object.definePrototype is not a function`

I try another way like this :

```
moment.locale('nl')
Vue.prototype.$moment = moment
```

But when I run the page, on the console exist error :

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: moment is not defined"`

If I put `import moment from 'moment'` directly in component vue, it works. But I want to put it globally

How can I solve this problem?

Note :

My component vue like this :

```
<template>
<b-card no-body>
    ...
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted">{{formatDate(data.date)}}</p>
    ...
</b-card>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
    props: ['data'],
    methods: {
        formatDate(date) {
            return this.$moment(date).format('YYYY MM DD')
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use moment, it's deprecated and far better alternatives exist as written here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: correct, `Object.definePrototype` is not something that exists - did you mean `Object.defineProperty` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.
In `main.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import moment from 'moment'
moment.locale('de');
Vue.prototype.moment = moment;
```

And in your component you can directly use moment as below

```
<template>
<b-card no-body>
    ...
      <p class="mb-0 text-muted">{{formatDate(data.date)}}</p>
    ...
</b-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['data'],
    methods: {
        formatDate(date) {
            return this.moment(date).format('YYYY MM DD')
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434454/why-line-number-doesnt-work-when-click-on-another-page Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax. There's no `Object.definePrototype`, the function you need is `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties`

Change your code

```
Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

to

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

Both define methods work fine for me.

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });

// or 

Vue.prototype.$moment = moment;
```

Since the less code, I can not point out accurately why you can not use $moment.

But, I guess you use this.$moment in data() (?)

Tips: You can't use `this` in data(), since the component isn't mounted yet.
Try to use it in `mounted` or `methods` section.

Also, the easiest way to use this.$moment, just import the package `vue-moment` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment).
This package already define $moment. All you need to do is import it and type `Vue.use(require("vue-moment"));` in your main.js.

Comment: I update my question. I add my vue component. I try your code. But it does not works. There exist error `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: moment is not defined"`

Comment: Hi @positivedeveloper, since you use the function `formateDate` in template, the formatDate first execute in template but not mounted yet. 

Please try the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-forked-jvfie7). 

Open your console and see what happend. First, the printMoment method print 
 this.$moment as `undefined`, but the second time you click the button, you can see it print the moment method correctly

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly, but I feel like I need to share this: Moment has been deprecated. Please look into other alternatives if needed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

This is a good replacement:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs

Answer (score -1):

i think its better to use vue-moment
see the link blow:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment

Comment: Moment is deprecated and using another 2nd package for a package is really not needed in this case. Just clutters your dependencies and increases size of the application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).